# Wso2 API Manager : API Produce and Consume JMS Messages

Tags: wso2, jms, wso2-api-manager

I have following requirement, is this possible to achieve in WSo2 API Manager. Please advise. I got few [article/pages](http://wso2.com/library/articles/2015/10/article-how-to-enable-wso2-api-manager-to-work-as-a-jms-producer/) with information on how to post request to message queue but none for how to consume message.

1. UI client calls a REST API exposed on the API gateway.
2. The backend service actually providing the implementation is a module
3. This module reads from a MQSeries queue an XML message, processes it and responds back to an outgoing queue.
4. So API gateway must be able to transform the REST/JSON payload to an XML payload and put it on the MQ Series queue
5. Wait synchronously and pick up response from another MQSeries queue.

Answer (score 3):

APIM does not support consuming JMS messages OOTB. But WSO2 ESB. See https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/ESB+as+a+JMS+Consumer

However, since APIM has ESB features installed by default, you should be able to deploy such a JMS consuming proxy in APIM too.

Have a try and post if you face any issues.